# How to setup a client server without localhost using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, client-server

I am very novice with socket programming so sorry about any simple questions

My objective is to create a server which sends to several clients a csv file, clients located in different locations

I have a question about the following initial part of server and client

```
#TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_IP = socket.gethostbyaddr("myip?")[0]
TCP_PORT = 9001
```

When debugging that line I get a valid isp domain but
If I do it this way I get an error that the Address is not valid

Shouldnt I place my real static ip in server script and in client script?

Comment: Do you have a static IP? If so, which interface has that IP? Make your server listen on that interface. If you're unsure about which interface, make it listen on all interfaces with `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Yes I have static IP from router so how I add the interface here